# `man <command>` not giving docs that (`which <command>`) executable points to

Tags: man

`man <command>` doesn't always point to the "right" (as in "given by `which <command>`"). Is there a way to make sure (or at least increase the chances that) I get docs that correspond to the command that will actually be executed?

#### EXAMPLE

With `pack` (a [wads](https://pypi.org/project/wads/) script) I get this:

```
$ which pack
.../dev/unix_scripts/pack
$ man pack                                                                                                                                  LIBPACK(3)

NAME
       libpack - support for connected components
...
```

Note that here `.../dev/unix_scripts/pack` doesn't actually have a man page, so I'd like the `man` to tell me it doesn't find it.

#### TRIED

If man took full paths to executable, I could do this:

```
$ which pack | man
```

This:

```
$ man 1 pack
No entry for pack in section 1 of the manual
```

but I'm not sure only looking in section 1 ("Executable programs or shell commands") is too restrictive.

#### General context

The underlying context is that I'm trying to write a (python) function that will get me some info on any "valid" (in the sense of `which <command>`) executable. A name is linked to a unique executable through `which`. How do I get docs-like information about that executable?

I (post my question on stackoverflow)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73814043/universal-help-for-terminal-commands], which was banished as "not a software question", so I reduced the question and posted it here.

Comment: Man operates on files in `MANPATH`. (Read `man man`.) Distros often package symlinks to manpages, effectively creating "aliases". If you don't want the specific manpage to be displayed when you supply a specific argument to man(1), you will need to organize (move/remove) manpages or symlinks to manpages yourself, including configuring your package manager to not undo your changes on next update.

Answer (score 0):

`man <command>` is inaccurate — distributions generally include more than man pages just for commands. This is what you’re running into here: `man pack` is showing you the documentation for a library.

You mention that you tried `man 1 pack`, but that you’re wondering whether that is too restrictive; it seems to me that if you’re only interested in commands, then that is a good approach. You may need to also look in section 8 in some cases, but for non-administrative commands, `man 1 foo` will match a command most of the time (the exception I can think of is `man 1 intro`).